# vlookup function rounding up in vba

Tags: vlookup

Does it exist a way to avoid getting a rounded up result when using vlookup formula in vba. Here is my code:

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow, pressurecolumn, lastcolumn As String, total As Integer, x, row, irow, column As Double
lastrow = Range("B8").End(xlDown).Value + 7

Range("Pump_design[Total Pipe losses from plantroom]").ClearContents
For Each row In Columns("EZ")
For irow = 8 To lastrow
total = 0
For column = 4 To 153
x = Cells(irow, column).Value
If Not IsEmpty(x) Then
total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(x, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 154, False)
End If
Next column
Cells(irow, "EZ") = Round(total, 4)
If Cells(irow, "EZ") = 0 Then Cells(irow, "EZ").ClearContents
Next irow
row = irow + 1
Next row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the trick get total as double instead of integer